# When I try to dynamically load a div, all the classes and ids aren't registering, even with .on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

EDIT: REQUESTED MORE CODE:

In my index.html  tags, it contains two divs:

```
<div id="index-banner">
  blabla
</div>

<div id="java-cheatsheet-placeholder"> </div>
```

Then my java-cheatsheet.html contains:

```
<div id="content">
    <h1>Java Cheat Sheet </h1>
    <input type="button" value="Show Keywords" id="keywordButton">

      <p> To help with remembering, some keywords will be hidden. Simply click or tap the box to reveal the
        important keyword(s). e.g. There are <span class="answer">eight</span> bits in a byte. Disable/Enable all the 
        hidden words by tapping the button at the top right. </p>
</div>
```

I then have a bunch of code, that is tested and works properly, if I push on the button(with an id of "keywordButton"), it either reveals or hides ALL the span elements with a class of "answer", but if you click on a specific span, it will hide/show that and only that word. This is fully functional on its own. But if I try using this (in my custom.js file):

```
$("#javaCheatSheet").click(function () {
    $("#java-cheatsheet-placeholder").load('../java-cheatsheet/javaSummary2.html');
    $("#index-banner").hide();
});
```

it loads the data, but clicking the button or the spans NO longer works, unless I also add

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/custom.js"></script>
```

in my java-cheatsheet.html file at the bottom. I of course don't want to do this, and would rather have .on() working with jquery, but if I try what most people have suggested:

```
$("#javaCheatSheet").on('click', '#keywordButton, .answer', function () {
    $("#java-cheatsheet-placeholder").load('../java-cheatsheet/javaSummary2.html');
    $("#index-banner").hide();
});
```

it doesn't even load the html into index.html at all >_>.

Comment: Read about [`Event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: The HTML code you provided in the fiddle is incomplete. For example, there is no `#javaCheatSheet`. Also, please copy your fiddle into a Stackoverflow code snippet

Comment: I have updated my post

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added jquery. With jquery your code works fine.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

see below.

```js
var toggleColorNotVisible = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
var toggleColorVisible = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
var backgroundColorVisible = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
var showAnswersButton = false;

$(document).on('click', '#keywordButton', function() {
  if (showAnswersButton) {
    $(".answer").css("color", toggleColorNotVisible);
    $(".answer").css("background-color", toggleColorNotVisible);
    $(".answer").each(function() {
      this.hideAnswers = false;
    });

  } else {
    $(".answer").css("color", toggleColorVisible);
    $(".answer").css("background-color", backgroundColorVisible);
    $(".answer").each(function() {
      this.hideAnswers = true;
    });
  }
  showAnswersButton = !showAnswersButton;
});

$(document).on('click', '.answer', function() {
  console.log("LOL")
  this.hideAnswers = this.hideAnswers || false;

  if (this.hideAnswers) {
    $(this).css("color", toggleColorNotVisible);
    $(this).css("background-color", toggleColorNotVisible);
  } else {
    $(this).css("color", toggleColorVisible);
    $(this).css("background-color", backgroundColorVisible);

  }
  this.hideAnswers = !this.hideAnswers;
});
```

```css
.answer {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #000000;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
#keywordButton {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  right: 1%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Show/Hide Keywords" id="keywordButton">
<hr>
<h2> Intro </h2>
<p>Stuff</p>
<hr>
<p>To help with remembering, some keywords will be hidden. Simply click or tap the box to reveal the important keyword(s). e.g. There are <span class="answer">eight</span> bits in a<span class="answer"> byte</span>. Disable/enable using button for all!
```

Comment: I definitely did. I think it might have something to do with materializecss?

Comment: I should say, I most certainly did in my .html, and have been using it quite a bit. On the jsfiddle I didn't. I'm very confused why this isn't working with materializecss framework, I feel like it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yeah I know I corrected myself, apologies, but with jsfiddle I can't have two HTML files regardless, and the issue is once I call the load, the .click methods don't even fire, because it seems that they don't identify the new added class and id in the body of index.html, which was taken from tutorial.java

Comment: Then use with $(document).on('click', '#button', callback); It should work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to use ^, meaning, do I use the callback, or what is #button? I have an id and a class element.

Comment: @VDog your #keywordButton button, see the code snippet.

Comment: @Prs unfortunately that didn't work, it's simply not firing >_>

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
$("#javaCheatSheet").on("click", "#keywordButton, .answer", function () {
    $("#index-banner").load('../java-cheatsheet/javaSummary2.html');
});
```

**Edit:**

```
$("#java-cheatsheet-placeholder").on("click", "#keywordButton, .answer", function () {
    // Show/hide answers here
});
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted to do, but unfortunately when I did this it didn't generate the dynamic code, nor cause any errors. But if I removed the "#keywordButton, .answer" part, it generated the html, but the main issue remained, where .answer and #keywordButton did nothing on click :(

Comment: @VDog You should show us more of your HTML/JS code.

Comment: You got it, I just updated my post providing much more detail, thank you!

Comment: @VDog Have you tried something like this? (edited answer)